# Синтаксическая ошибка при проверке инпута

Tags: html, jquery, json, веб-программирование

В этой строке ошибка : submit = form.find('button['type=submit']) , подскажете как исправить ?

вот весь код:

```
    (function($){

var checkMobileOperator = function(){

//var operators  = window.operators;
var operators = [{'code'909:, 'name''Beeline'},{code: '921', name: 'MTS'}];

this.check = function(value){

value = value.replace(/(?:^(7|\+7|8))*(?:\(|\))/g,'');

if (value.length == 9) {

var code = value.substr(0,3);

for (var i = 0, len =  operators.length; i < len; i++) {
    if ( operators[i].code === code)
        return operators[i].name; 
    }

    return null; 
}

}

}

var CheckMobileOperator = new checkMobileOperator();

var form = $('form'),
input = $('#phone', form),
submit =form.find('button['type=submit'])
submit.addAttr('disabled','disabled');

input.on('keydown, function(e){
if (!((which >= 48 && which <= 57) || which == 13)){
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
 }

!!checkMobileOperator.check(input.val()) && submit.removeAttr('disabled');

 });
}(jQuery)
```

Comment: Кавычку допишите + внутренние кавычки сделайте `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в кавычках. Можно исправить так:

```
submit = form.find('button["type=submit"]');
```